# YA book with teen becoming a (super?)hero

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I am looking for a book I read in 2014. I don't remember what the story is about, but I wrote down this citation (And unfortunatly never noted down the source) :

> "After becoming a hero he would still be ridiculous, he knew it, being
> ridiculous is like eye color it never changes. But, like eye color,
> when you become a hero, it matters a little less."

I know it was a YA novel, and for the longest time I was sure it was from "Thirteen days to midnight" but I just read it and it is definitively not the source of the quote. So I was also sure the cover was blue or greenish, but it is possible I get the two books mixed up.

I originally read the book in French, so the quote I accualy wrote down is the following, but at the time I mostly read books translated from anglophone authors.

> "Après sa transformation en héros il serait encore ridicule, il le
> savait, être ridicule c'est comme la couleur des yeux ça ne change
> jamais. Pourtant, comme la couleur des yeux, quand on devient un
> héros, ça compte un peu moins."

I hope it sounds familiar to someone, it has been bugging me for years!